# Installing WordPress on a long temporary URL from host

Tags: theme-development, installation, server

I'm designing and developing a WordPress site to replace a 2005 HTML/CSS site.

My client's hosting company said they were switching systems and his is one of the last to move, so they set me up on a new server (so I wouldn't break anything?) and said they would switch the DNS records when it's ready.

With WordPress installed at the root, this is my URL (slightly changed):

http://11.11.11.111/plesk-site-preview/example.com/11.11.11.111/

I have a vanilla install of WordPress there and the front end looks fine, but I have two problems in my wp-admin:

1. All theme screenshots flash the correct screenshot, then show broken images. The URLs change to http://example.com/wp-content/themes/etc. instead of using the above URL. (I can share a video if it helps).
2. Nothing happens when I go to add a new theme. It's just a blank gray page:
   [image: Add Themes page is blank.]

Normally, I would install WordPress at a subdirectory so I have never experienced these problems before. I've also never worked with this host company. I can't tell if there's something I can do in WordPress that will fix this or if it's not an issue at my level.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I have debugging turned on and don't have any errors.

**Edit:**

I have new developments in the problem.

I created a couple of pages, thinking I'd get at least something done on the site. Then I went to select a static page for the home page and saw that the preview also doesn't work (it's also looking under http://example.com/ for some of the resources).

It was just showing the loading icon while in the customizer, so I closed it. Then I got logged out and I can't log back in. The page simply refreshes when I press "Log In," with no error message. I tried resetting my password in phpMyAdmin, but that didn't work. Then I saw that `.htaccess` was now only 51 bytes, so I opened it and saw that the WordPress section was completely wiped out. So I added that back in (though I feel now I'm scooping water out of a sinking ship).

Now all the pages on the front-end are giving a 403 errors. I can only access `wp-login.php`, but cannot login.

**2nd Edit:**

Okay so this is kind of a solution, but not really because I didn't figure out why WordPress didn't like that long URL. I went to the old site and manually saved each file, uploaded it all to the new server, and had them change the DNS records. That way I could bypass the issue altogether.

I still had the issue of the 403, which led me to this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-403-forbidden-after-installing

I had to change the `.htaccess` file at the root to allow `index.php` instead of just `index.html`.

I'm still wondering if other people have had similar issues or if there's a specific reason the long URL didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

check 'permalinks' 
and check wp-content/themes --> make it 777 permissions

Comment: Permalinks have the full URL listed. I also tried flushing them. Changed wp-content/themes to 777 (from 755) but that didn't change anything either. Thanks for the ideas though!